What is Enforcing Adequate Vgs Regardless of Gate Drive Voltage?
I am designing a bidirectional power switch (BPS) which connects a power source to a variable current load. The MOSFET I am using have a Vgs_th of 1V-2.5V.
Referencing my schematic:
I had thought if the voltage at IN were to be 2.5V higher than GATE, the BPS would not turn on. Or at least would start to turn on then turn on. It would start to turn on because SOURCE (although floating) is sitting at some lower voltage than the on state of GATE. But when GATE is enabled SOURCE would begin to rise to IN.
Since IN > GATE, at some point SOURCE > GATE and therefore Vgs would be less than Vth.
Simulations show this happening but even with quite low GATE voltage it throttles the SOURCE voltage in order to maintain adequate Vgs to keep the switch on.
I dont actually care what the voltage is at the output of the BPS, what I care about is the ability to draw the requested amount of current which looks to work. But.. would like to better understand what's happening here.
What I think is happening:
From reading: https://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE3040/Lectures/Lecture24-MOS%20Transistors.pdf
It seems like the first MOSFET (U1) is reaching the condition Vds>Vsat and the inversion layer is pinched near the Drain and the channel length depletes such that adequate Vds is dropped so that adequate Vgs can be maintained.
From the link:

This seems further supported but the increase in power loss in U1 on as GATE voltage decreases.
Assuming the above is correct:
Where is my lack of understanding of MOSFETs/electronics to predict that this would have happened?
What determines Vsat? This doesnt seem to be a datasheet parameter. And why does it seem to conveniently be Vgate - Vth so that the switch always turns on?
Schematic/Datasheets:
MOSFET: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr3110zpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566cf6e2268a
At t=100ms: GATE voltage enabled
At t=300ms: DAC voltage swept to request 0-300mA from V1

Simulation Plots:



What determines Vsat? This doesnt seem to be a datasheet parameter.

When, for a MOSFET, \$V_{GS}>V_{TH}\$ and \$V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$, the MOSFET is said to be in saturation.
In saturation, the gate to source voltage will be approximately related to the drain current by a "square law".
$$I_D \approx k\times(V_{GS}-V_{Th})^2$$
where \$k\$ is a constant, specific to each MOSFET, associated with transconductance.
In re-arranged form, this square law can be expressed as:
$$V_{GS} \approx V_{TH} + \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{k}}$$
In saturation, \$I_D\$ is fairly independent of \$V_{DS}\$.
The following graph from @Adam Lawrence's answer to another question, shows the characteristic curves of a typical MOSFET

The red curve shows the boundary, to the right of which the MOSFET is saturated.
We can define the saturation voltage for a given drain current as
$$V_{DS(SAT)}=V_{GS}-V_{Th} \approx \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{k}} $$
Having defined \$V_{DS(SAT)}\$ we can say that a MOSFET is in saturation if, for a given \$I_D\$,
$$V_{DS} \ge V_{DS(SAT)}$$

I had thought if the voltage at IN were to be 2.5V higher than GATE, the BPS would not turn on.


And why does [the voltage across U1] seem to conveniently be Vgate - Vth so that the switch always turns on?

By Kirchhoff's voltage law,
$$V_1 = V_{DS(U1)} + V_{DS(U2)} + V_{DS(U3)} + IR_9$$
A 3 terminal MOSFET can only block current in one direction. Even if the gate voltage does not create a channel for current to flow from drain to source in an N-channel MOSFET, the body diode will permit current to flow from source to drain.
Thus, U2 in your circuit, is effectively just a forward biased diode, and will have at most one diode forward voltage drop across it.
Thus, if we neglect \$V_{DS(U2)}\$ we have
$$V_1 \approx V_{DS(U1)} + V_{DS(U3)} + IR_9$$
We can similarly neglect the voltage across \$R_9\$, which we presume to be quite small, so
$$V_1 \approx V_{DS(U1)} + V_{DS(U3)}$$
If U3 is conducting, but U1 were not, then nearly the full voltage of \$V_1\$ would be across U1, so, \$V_{DS(U1)}\$ would be greater than \$V_{Th}\$. But by assumption, \$V_{DS(U1)} = V_{GS(U1)} + 2.5 \;\text{V}\$, so \$V_{GS(U1)} > V_{Th}\$, so U1 must be conducting.
With the circuit given, if U3 is conducting, U1 must be conducting, and furthermore, since \$V_{DS(U1)} > V_{GS(U1)}\$, U1 is in saturation.
Since if U3 is conducting, and U1 is in saturation,
$$V_{GS(U1)} \approx V_{TH} + \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{k}}$$
so \$V_{GS(U1)}\$ is not identically equal to \$V_{Th}\$ as you suppose. The two voltages are very close when \$I_D\$ is small, but because of the square law
$$V_{GS} \approx V_{TH} + \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{k}}$$
when \$I_D\$ is large, there will be a noticeable difference between \$V_{GS(U1)}\$ and \$V_{Th}\$.
Note that U1 in this circuit is wired as a source-follower (i.e. it is in common drain configuration). The results about saturation above are generally true for MOSFETS in source-follower (common drain) configuration.
Further, the combination of U1 and U3 (with U2 neglected) is known as a cascode configuration, and the results about saturation above are also generally true for MOSFETS in cascode configuration.

Thank you for response and the edit to relate more to my specific circuit. This answer along with this youtube video helped me understand this concept better.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgpzQC3MCuA&t=1672s

@Michael. Great. I'm glad you were able to understand my answer (with some help). I thought about re-writing it for more clarity, but didn't :-) ...

It's simple -- if you want to use an N-channel MOSFET as a high-side switch, you need to be able to drive its gate to a voltage that's well above the drain/source voltage. This usually involves a "floating" power supply for the gate driver that is referenced to the MOSFET source terminal.
In some switching power converters, this floating supply can be created by a simple diode-capacitor charge pump. In other applications, an isolated DC-DC converter can be used.
In high-voltage applications, you'll need to take additional precautions to make sure that VGS(max) is never exceeded. This usually takes the form of a zener diode connected between the gate and source terminals.


Where is my lack of understanding of MOSFETs/electronics to predict that this would have happened?

You're operating the MOSFET as a "source follower".
As your simulation shows, as the gate voltage rises, the source voltage rises to follow it, with an offset of Vth, the MOSFET's gate threshold voltage.

What determines Vsat? This doesn't seem to be a datasheet parameter.

No, it isn't, because it depends on VGS.
When a MOSFET is in saturation, the drain current is basically constant, and VDS can have an arbitrary value.
But most datasheets show a family of curves, showing ID versus VDS for a variety of values of VGS.
On this graph, you can see the onset of saturation for each value of VGS.

And why does it seem to conveniently be Vgate - Vth so that the switch always turns on?

Because if the source voltage were to rise above that value, it would reduce VGS and therefore reduce the current through the channel.
This negative feedback would then tend to drive the source voltage back down.

I did explore that. The schematic/scope of application was watered down for the sake of the question. I do agree that this circuit would be made "better" with an isolated gate drive but the non-isolated drive does work for enough operational conditions. My question is more so to understand this circuit rather than possible improvements. But thank you - obviously do appreciate any suggestions for betterment.

I do have a zener across gate and source in my complete schematic. I tried to remove everything I didnt think helpful for getting the question across. Maybe some things were worth keeping.
